# Unicorn Rails - Takes 100% CPU while starting in production mode

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unicorn

We are using Unicorn_Rails + nginx.
It works well in development mode and production mode in my system ( 4GB Ram , Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P8600  @ 2.40GHz)
i am able to start 10 workers in local system but unable to start more than 2 in any case in production
sometimes it works but need to wait for 15- 20 mts
It takes 99.6% CPU all the time while starting unicorn_rails

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5507  @ 2.27GHz
but it hangs in amazon ( m1.small instance ) 
1.73 GB RAM

i find no one talking about a slow startup using unicorn_rails anywhere ...

Comment: did you figure this out? i have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Rails startup is CPU-bound, it will (almost) always use 100% of CPU all the time. Looks like the load you are trying to put on that instance is too large; you only need 1 worker per CPU core, and m1.small has just one.

When you try to start 10 workers, they're sharing both CPU and I/O, and a lot of I/O requests always slows the subsystem down. You can add `preload_app true` clause in your `config/unicorn.rb`; this should lower the startup time, but you really do not need 10 workers on such an instance.

Comment: thank you for the immediate reply . i just love it.. surely i will try with preload_app true . btb i have only 1 worker configured in unicorn.rb conf file.

Comment: then, that's strange. Amazon instances aren't very powerful, but starting Rails definitely shouldn't take 15 minutes -- heck, 1.5 minutes is enough on my old Pentium III! (by the way, preload_app won't change anything if you only have 1 worker). Try starting it via `strace -f` (without daemonization) and check if some syscalls take much more time than expected.

Comment: it i give -D (daemonize) it takes infinite time . but when i run it without -D it works atlease after 5-10 mts. and i leave the terminal for session out .. SAD !!!!

Comment: start with fewer workers you can always add to the worker pool on the fly with __kill -TTIN <process id>__

Comment: 1 thing I observed,
If you give wrong database name then every unicorn worker keeps trying to connect database which is not present and in that case it takes 100 % CPU